# Unattended-Upgrades override Allowed-Origins

Tags: ubuntu, security, apt, unattended

I am trying to set the `Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins` so that it only is allowed for security updates. I would like to do this in a later config in the `apt.conf.d` leaving the default `50unattended-upgrades` config as the default and just overriding.

In my `99-unattended-upgrades` I am setting the following:

```
// Only allow security origin
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
};
```

However, this seems to be *merged* with the existing config (rather than just nuking it completely) as when I do an `apt-config dump` I can see the default settings in there.

I also tried setting it with the following:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
```

Also did not work.

I *could* simply comment out the lines in `50unattended-updates`, but, I'd really like to leave the original files pristine if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of digging in apt source code and then in apt-conf manual page it turns out that there is a way

> [...]#clear is used to erase a part of the configuration tree. The specified element and all its descendants are erased. (Note that these
>   lines also need to end with a semicolon.)
>
> The #clear command is the
>   only way to delete a list or a complete scope. Reopening a scope (or
>   using the syntax described below with an appended ::) will not
>   override previously written entries. Options can only be overridden by
>   addressing a new value to them - lists and scopes can't be overridden,
>   only cleared.

So this would get you what you want:

```
#clear Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins;
// Only allow security origin
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
};
```

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt.conf.5.en.html

Comment: I just wanted to quickly comment "thanks"! I'll test this out today and see how it goes. I've been away for the last few days hence the slow reply.

Comment: no worries, don't forget to upvote & accept the answer ;)